# Special characters training NLP models

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I just started with NLP in bots, where a user ask a question that is classified by LUIS and then forwarded to QnAMaker to get an answer, and I have noticed that it behaves strangely with Spanish since we have accented characters and double question marks (¿?). For example:

```
[1] ¿qué es NLP?
[2] que es NLP
```

If I train my model with the first one and test it with the second one, the model won't identify both of them with the same intent. This is a very common way to communicate in Spanish since some people tend to save time by avoiding accented charactes and punctuation.

My questions are:

- Should I normalize every utterance in my model (removing accents,
  punctuation, etc.)? Or should I train it with every different example?
- Are there any guidelines for training NLP models that I can base my work in?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I normalize every utterance in my model (removing accents,
>   punctuation, etc.)? Or should I train it with every different example?

That really depends on what you'd want, but to not have to duplicate a bunch of work, it'd probably just be better to just normalize every utterance in your model.

Then what you could do on your bot level, is strip away characters that have accents or are considered "special"/replace with normalized characters, before sending the utterance to LUIS to predict intent with